# How is called this thumbnail slider feature

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, slideshow

I am new to wordpress, and I am trying to create new website. I found really nice-looking theme, but when I installed and activated it, it looks very simple compared to the preview page. Is it due to that I have to pay to make my website look 100% similar as preview?

Anyway, how is this feature called, that you can see in the picture? There are 3 thumbnails, that are sliding after some time, and they are clickable. Could anyone share the name, and how can I implement it myself?

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: You should be checking with the theme developer as to how to do things, the chances of someone here knowing what the Faith Blog theme does or how it works are minimal.  Also, an important thing to keep in mind is that when you're looking at themes demos online there's usually a lot of hours that have gone into getting them to look good.  As an experiment I once downloaded a third-party theme & attempted to replicate the demo exactly, after about 60 hours of "toggle, click, saving" I gave up & was only about 2/3s of the way through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a Carousel or Slideshow gallery